# Drupal 7 custom voting solution

Tags: drupal-7, polling, drupal-webform, voting-system

I need to create a voting system which will essentially consist of several forms each with a list of radio buttons, of which a single choice can be made. Submission of the form loads the next one, this will go on for about 10 pages, before finally sending the user to a generic data capture form where they will submit their credentials for inclusion in a prize draw.

Several approaches spring to mind:

1. Create a clone of the core poll module and modify it to achieve the required functionality
2. Modify the drupal quiz module to allow anonymous recording of votes (the fact that it doesn't is the only thing stopping me approaching it this way, it works almost exactly as I want it to otherwise)
3. Create something completely custom using the webform module.

I just wondered if anyone had come across this same problem/dilemma and could share any knowledge???

Answer (score 0):

Can you accomplish this with a multi-page webform? You can build the webform by adding a "select options" field, followed by a "page break", then another "select options" field, and another "page break", etc, etc.

You can limit the select options field to 1 answer. Then when you want to gather their information, just add simple text fields at the end.